# how to resolve this ValueError: only 2 non-keyword arguments accepted sklearn python

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, valueerror

hello i am new to sklearn in python and iam trying to learn it and use this module to predict some numbers based on two features here is the error i am getting:

> ValueError: only 2 non-keyword arguments accepted

and here is my code:

```
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
    import numpy as np

    trainingData = np.array([[861, 16012018], [860, 12012018], [859, 9012018], [858, 5012018], [857, 2012018], [856, 29122017], [855, 26122017], [854, 22122017], [853, 19122017]])
    trainingScores = np.array([11,18,23,33,34,6],[10,19,21,33,34,1], [14,18,22,23,31,6],[16,22,29,31,33,10],[21,24,27,30,31,6],[1,14,15,20,27,7],[1,9,10,11,15,8],[2,9,27,31,35,1],[7,13,18,22,33,2])

    clf = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True)
    clf.fit(trainingScores,trainingData)

   predictionData = np.array([862, 19012018 ])
   x=clf.predict(predictionData)
   print(x)
```

Comment: What is the trainingData and trainingScores here? Is this a multi-output regression problem?

Comment: Also you are using the fit() wrong. It should be fit(X, y) but you are doing fit(y, X)

Comment: the training data consist of 2 features the  number and the date the numbers are selected and the training score is 6 random numbers

Comment: ps. i still get the error after fixing the fit()

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure what you are trying to do here, but change this line:

```
trainingScores = np.array([11,18,23,33,34,6],[10,19,21,33,34,1], [14,18,22,23,31,6],[16,22,29,31,33,10],[21,24,27,30,31,6],[1,14,15,20,27,7],[1,9,10,11,15,8],[2,9,27,31,35,1],[7,13,18,22,33,2])
```

to this (Notice the extra square brackets around your data):

```
trainingScores = np.array([[11,18,23,33,34,6],[10,19,21,33,34,1], [14,18,22,23,31,6],[16,22,29,31,33,10],[21,24,27,30,31,6],[1,14,15,20,27,7],[1,9,10,11,15,8],[2,9,27,31,35,1],[7,13,18,22,33,2]])
```

Then change the order of params in fit() like this:

```
clf.fit(trainingData,trainingScores)
```

And finally change prediction data like this (again look at the extra square brackets):

```
predictionData = np.array([[862, 19012018]])
```

After that your code will run.

Comment: quick question how would i go about splitting and the data into training and testing and then prediction ????

Comment: @dondeveto Please first explain to me what are you trying to do? Why does data have 2 features and scores have 6 targets?

Comment: i want to see / predict the numbers of six people. i want to see if there is a pattern to their selection. the features are the number of guess and date when guess are made

Comment: @dondeveto Use [`train_test_split()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

Answer (score -2):

You are doing a linear regression code in ML and try to change this line with

```
trainingScores = np.array(
  [11,18,23,33,34,6],
  [10,19,21,33,34,1], 
  [14,18,22,23,31,6],
  [16,22,29,31,33,10],
  [21,24,27,30,31,6],
  [1,14,15,20,27,7],
  [1,9,10,11,15,8],
  [2,9,27,31,35,1],
  [7,13,18,22,33,2]
)
```

Comment: Try to change *which* line?