# Import from a file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some code like:

(main.py)

```
from importfile import *
```

(importfile.py)

```
import numpy as np
```

I have now tried the following with my main file:

```
npArray = np.array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
print(npArray)
```

But I get an error that says:

> IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question. The question title should also be in English.

Comment: That error is a syntax error, syntax is checked before the program even starts to run so before any imports are even attempted. Look for improper indents elsewhere

Comment: Your problem is not due to your imports, but rather to your indentation. Please update your question with your code as well as the precise error, including the line number it is on.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help, unfortunately the import still doesn't work properly, I added code and errors in the question under Edit.

Comment: Why do you say that the import doesn't doesn't work? The errors are not related to the imports, they are related to your code. Also why do you import a file just to import something else?

Comment: You forgot the brackets... It needs to be: `np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])`

Comment: Dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48342143/how-to-resolve-this-valueerror-only-2-non-keyword-arguments-accepted-sklearn-py This is from googling the exact error

Comment: What exactly is this question about? Is it about importing, indentation or instantiating an ``np.array``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the numbers as list:

```
npArray = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

Comment: Ah right, I don't know how that could happen to me now, but I do know. Sorry and thanks